# Is Resharper's recommendation to make my private method static a good recommendation?

Tags: c#, function, static, resharper

I've recently noticed that when I create private methods that set a few fields in the objects passed to them that Resharper puts up a hint stating that the method can be made static.

Here's a greatly simplified example of the sort of method I might have.

```
private void MakeStatusTheSame(MyClass mc, MySecondClass msc)
{
    mc.Status = msc.Status;
}
```

When I've got a method like this, Resharper provides a recommendation that the method can be made static.

I try to avoid making public methods static since they wreck havoc on unit tests...but I'm not sure that the same applies for private methods.

Is Resharper's recommendation a valid best practice or should I just turn it off?

Comment: Public methods are totally testable, *if they don't cause side-effects.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that's definitely a prime candidate for a static method. It's not changing any of the class's properties, fields, etc.

Here's an example:

```
class MyClass
{
  public static void MakeStatusTheSame(MyClass mc, MySecondClass msc)
  {
     mc.status = msc.status;
  }

  private void MakeStatusTheSame(MySecondClass msc)
  {
    this.status = msc.status;
  }

  private int status;
}
```

Also, you could make it an extension method (which would also be static):

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static MyClass MakeStatusTheSame(this MyClass mc, MySecondClass msc)
  {
    mc.status = msc.status
    return mc; /* make the method chainable */
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

At the risk of sounding like a contrarian, I've got to admit that I don't like mixing static methods with instance methods; and I dislike static methods in general. Static methods are difficult to test, difficult to override, and difficult to maintain. I prefer to stick all static methods for dealing with Foo objects into a single FooUtils class -- or, better yet, into a singleton instance of a FooSomethingDoer class.

Of course, static methods make perfect sense in some cases -- for example, when creating the aforementioned singletons, or factories, etc. I'm not saying that all static methods are made of pure evil; I just prefer to err on the side of avoiding them when possible.

Comment: I'm with you. I only make methods static when it makes sense to, not just because i "can".

Comment: I would agree for public, protected, and internal - but not for private methods. There's some discussion on the Net if Utils classes are a code smell; I'd suggest using them with care.

Comment: Agreed.  Making a method static is an attempt to communicate information related to the usage of that method.  Making everything static just makes no sense.

Answer (score 7):

I think so; seeing that a method is static is a clear indication that the method should *not* be interacting with any instance members.

Imagine debugging a non-static method and realizing the instance isn't being touched. Instant smell, and if there isn't a comment explaining what the function does, you could be distracted from the real problem.

Comment: +1 for making it clear that the method should not be interacting with instance members. I definitely want people to think twice before modifying that particular code with calls to methods on instance members. By marking the private method static if someone modified the code to use an instance member they'd get a compile warning which should at least make them think for a few seconds.

Comment: I had R# recommend making a method static just minutes ago, only to find a compile error trying to access an instance field.  First time ever that it's happened though, something must have confused it.

Comment: What do you mean by interacting ? Modifying values ? Or this includes reading values?

Comment: @guiomie, either of those operations. For example, `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` takes as a parameter the data it uses, rather than using an instance member value.

Answer (score 4):

I usually go with R#'s recommendation. It's a private method, so (hopefully) you're not writing unit tests against it. Making it static explicitly states that it doesn't use any instance members, which makes it easier to inspect for side effects.